# Apple Push Notification on Mac for Application not on appstore

Tags: macos, cocoa, push-notification, apn

I am trying to integrate Push notification service on cocoa application but my application is not eligible to submit on app store.

Does anyone have idea that can we use push notification (APNs) for application outside mac app store ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you need to sign your app with a provision profile for the store to use the service

---

compare also: https://developer.streamezzo.com/tools/how-use-push-notification#Apple

Comment: I won't have any provision profile. I am using developer ID certificate which doesn't need any provision profile.

So is there any possibility to use APNs or any push service in application?

Comment: "no, you need to sign your app with a provision profile for the store to use the service"